# Javascript/jQuery registration form issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay so I am having issues with my script, not sure what the issue is, everything in my eyes seems to check up. but hopefully you guys can tell what the issue is (I haven't made the PHP script submit the registration to the database, but the script never returns)

So the issue is basically, after clicking the register button it does absolutely nothing, no error logs, nothing shows up.

Here's the Register.php file located at c:/website/@account/register.php

```
    <?php
    include("@includes/database.php");
    include("@includes/init.php");

    $x1 = rand(2,15);
    $x2 = rand(1,14);

    //Get Captcha Answer
    $first = $x1;
    $second = $x2;
    $answer = $first + $second;

    if ($user -> LoggedIn())
    {
    header('Location: index.php?page=Dashboard');
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js">
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Business Name | Registration</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="@assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="@assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="@assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="@assets/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="@assets/css/colors.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@assets/js/plugins/loaders/pace.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@assets/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@assets/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@assets/js/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@assets/js/plugins/forms/styling/uniform.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@assets/js/core/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@assets/js/pages/login.js"></script>
                <script>
            function register()
            {
            var username=$('#username').val();
            var password=$('#password').val();
            var rpassword=$('#rpassword').val();
            var email=$('#email').val();
            var captcharesult=$('#captcharesult').val();
            var answer="<?php echo $answer; ?>";
            document.getElementById("registerdiv").style.display="none";
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("registerdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("registerdiv").style.display="inline";
                if (xmlhttp.responseText.search("Redirecting") != -1)
                {
                setInterval(function(){window.location="google.com"},3000);
                }
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","login.php?type=register",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&repeatpassword=" + repeatpassword + "&email=" + email + "&captcharesult=" + captcharesult + "&answer=" + answer);
            }
            </script>
    </head>

<body>

    <div class="page-container login-container">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <!-- Advanced login -->
                     <form method="post" action="" name="register">
                        <div class="panel panel-body login-form">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <h5 class="content-group">Business Name <small class="display-block">Account Registration</small></h5>
                                <div id="registerdiv" style="display:inline"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                                <div class="form-control-feedback">
                                    <i class="icon-user-check text-muted"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                                <div class="form-control-feedback">
                                    <i class="icon-mail5 text-muted"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                                <div class="form-control-feedback">
                                    <i class="icon-lock2 text-muted"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="repeatpassword" id="repeatpassword" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                                <div class="form-control-feedback">
                                    <i class="icon-lock2 text-muted"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcharesult" id="captcharesult" placeholder="<?php echo ''.$x1.'+'.$x2.'?'; ?>">
                                <div class="form-control-feedback">
                                    <i class="icon-info3 text-muted"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <input name="one" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $x1; ?>" />
                            <input name="two" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $x2; ?>" />

                            <button type="button" onclick="register()"class="btn bg-primary btn-block btn-lg">Register</button>
                            <button name="login" id="login" type="submit" class="btn bg-success btn-block btn-lg">Login</button>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <center>
                    <div class="text-muted">
                        &copy; 2015-<?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="https://Business Name.com/">Business Name</a>
                    </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the login.php located at c:/website/login.php

```
 <?php
                        include("@includes/database.php");
                        include("@includes/init.php");

                        if ($type == 'register')
                        {

                        //Get Registration Info
                        $username = $_POST['username'];
                        $email = $_POST['email'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $repeatpassword = $_POST['repeatpassword'];
                        $captcharesult = $_POST['captcharesult'];

                        //Errors
                        $errors = 0;

                        //Check If Everything Is Filled
                        if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($repeatpassword) || empty($captcharesult))
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert bg-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><span class="text-semibold">Oops!</span> You forgot to fill in all fields</a>!</div>';
                            $errors = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $errors = 0;
                        }

                        //Validate Username
                        if ($errors == 0)
                        {
                        if (!ctype_alnum($username) || strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 15)
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert bg-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><span class="text-semibold">Oops!</span> Username is not valid</a>!</div>';
                            $errors = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $errors = 0;
                        }
                        }

                        //Check If Username Is Taken
                        if ($errors == 0)
                        {
                            $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
                            $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
                            $countUser = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
                        if ($countUser > 0)
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert bg-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><span class="text-semibold">Oops!</span> Username is already in use</a>!</div>';
                            $errors = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $errors = 0;
                        }
                        }

                        //Validate Email
                        if ($errors == 0)
                        {
                        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                        {
                             echo '<div class="alert bg-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><span class="text-semibold">Oops!</span> Email is not valid</a>!</div>';
                            $errors = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $errors = 0;    
                        }
                        }

                        //Check If Email In Use
                        if ($errors == 0)
                        {
                        $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email");
                        $SQL -> execute(array(':email' => $email));
                        $countEmail = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
                        if ($countEmail > 0)
                        {
                             echo '<div class="alert bg-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><span class="text-semibold">Oops!</span> Email is already in use</a>!</div>';
                            $errors = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $errors = 0;    
                        }
    }

                        //Check Passwords
                        if ($errors == 0)
                        {
                        if ($password != $repeatpassword)
                        {
                             echo '<div class="alert bg-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><span class="text-semibold">Oops!</span> Passwords do not match</a>!</div>';
                            $errors = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $errors = 0;
                        }
                        }

                        //Check Captcha                             
                        if ($errors == 0)
                        {
                        if ($captcharesult == $answer)
                        {
                            $errors = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             echo '<div class="alert bg-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><span class="text-semibold">Oops!</span> Captcha is invalid</a>!</div>';
                            $errors = 1;
                        }
                        }


                        }
                        ?>
```

Comment: Why you're using XMLHttpRequest instead of jQuery ajax?

Comment: Are you getting errors in your script?

Comment: Please stop explaining that you are young and inexperienced, that's neither here nor there. Give us the error - where and what happens?

Comment: That's the thing, I get no errors, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things I would like to point out. First, when you click on <kbd>Register</kbd> button, you'll get this error:

> TypeError: register is not a function

The reason is, the `<form>` tag in your html code has `name="register"` just like the name of the function. And because of that some browsers can access the node elements just by specifying the name in the js code and then the function defined is overridden by the element in the DOM.

So you need to change the function name or the attribute `name` in `<form>` tag. I've changed the function name from `register()` to `registration()`.

Second, change `var rpassword=$('#rpassword').val();` to `var rpassword=$('#repeatpassword').val();`

And third, in your `send()` function, change `..."&repeatpassword=" + repeatpassword + "&email="...` to `..."&repeatpassword=" + rpassword+ "&email="...`

**Solution:**

Your HTML and JavaScript code should be like this:

```
// your code

<button type="button" onclick="registration()" class="btn bg-primary btn-block btn-lg">Register</button>

// your code

<script>
    function registration(){
        var username=$('#username').val();
        var password=$('#password').val();
        var rpassword=$('#repeatpassword').val();
        var email=$('#email').val();
        var captcharesult=$('#captcharesult').val();
        var answer="<?php echo $answer; ?>";
        document.getElementById("registerdiv").style.display="none";
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("registerdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("registerdiv").style.display="inline";
                if (xmlhttp.responseText.search("Redirecting") != -1){
                    setInterval(function(){window.location="google.com"},3000);
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","login.php?type=register",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&repeatpassword=" + rpassword + "&email=" + email + "&captcharesult=" + captcharesult + "&answer=" + answer);
    }
</script>
```

And your **login.php** page should be like this:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['answer']) && isset($_POST['captcharesult']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['repeatpassword']) && isset($_POST['username'])){

        if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == "register"){

            //Get Registration Info
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $repeatpassword = $_POST['repeatpassword'];
            $captcharesult = $_POST['captcharesult'];

            // now the rest of your code

        }

    }

?>
```

**Sidenote:** Use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of native ajax, it's much more simple and elegant.

Comment: I've fixed everything you had pointed out, still no results. Not sure what the issue is. I'm certain that I have included all the files needed.

Comment: @JasonMelendez In place of `// now the rest of your code` in login.php page, just echo this, `echo "working";`, and see if it's working or not.

Comment: I had fixed the issue, I accidentally made a minor misplacement everything had worked out perfectly for me thanks so much for your time and assistance, you're a savior =)

Comment: @JasonMelendez Glad I could help. :)

Comment: I do seem to actually not receive an error/notification after the user check in my login.php.

Comment: I figured out the issue, forgot that I had to include the database and init file.